# Trying VLCJ 4.4.4 on Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, video-streaming

I am trying to insert a recording dialog in my application to capture the screen during some simulation. Searching on Internet I've found VLCJ as a nice solution to start working on that but running the tutorial found in the official page (http://capricasoftware.co.uk/projects/vlcj-4/tutorials/my-first-media-player)

```
package Prueba;

import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent;

public class Tutorial {

    private static Tutorial thisApp;

    private final JFrame frame;

    private final EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent mediaPlayerComponent;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        thisApp = new Tutorial();
    }

    public Tutorial() {
        frame = new JFrame("My First Media Player");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                mediaPlayerComponent.release();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
        frame.setContentPane(mediaPlayerComponent);

        frame.setVisible(true);

        mediaPlayerComponent.mediaPlayer().media().play(args[0]);
    }
}
```

Doing this, it returns an the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: uk/co/caprica/vlcj/player/component/EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
```

And I'm completely clueless about it, because I am using jdk 1.8.0_251, which is higher than 1.6 required. Can anyone guide me a bit? :')

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are using the version of `VLCJ` which was developed in `Java Version 9` or above. Since you are using `Java Version 8`, your program can't execute the compiled code from the `VLCJ`. _**Solution**_: Use lower version of `VLCJ`. I use `VLCJ 3` and it works perfectly. Here's the link I could find for `VLCJ 3.10`, https://libraries.io/maven/uk.co.caprica:vlcj

Comment: vlcj-4.4.x baseline is Java 1.6. to double-check this I unpacked the jar and used javap to get the major class version - it reports 50, which is Java 1.6, so something else is wrong here. vlcj-4.5.x was a folly involving the Java Module System which did include a jump to Java 11, but that has now been abandoned. So check which version of vlcj you're actually using.

Comment: Thank you both of you. Yes, it was that issue; after that, just some stuff with libraries and works fine. Solved!